# Using Checkbox in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm implementing a project in `django`. I have two models named **Studio** and **Template**.

```
class Studio(models.Model):
    studio_id = models.IntegerField()

class Template(models.Model):
    template_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to map `Template`s with `Studio`s. One Studio can have multiple templates. so I created model that **StudioTemplateMapping**.

```
class StudioTemplateMapping(models.Model):
    studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template)
```

in **admin.py**

```
class StudioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('studio_id', )

class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('template_id', )

class StudioTemplateMappingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('studio', 'template)

admin.studio.register(Studio, StudioAdmin)
admin.studio.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)
admin.studio.register(StudioTemplateMapping, StudioTemplateMappingAdmin)
```

when I allocate studio with template, it should display all existing templates in checkbox. I could not displayed in checkbox view. could anyone suggest any way to display all templates in checkbox view and allocate with studio.